# Defualt id generated by Eclipse has char inside the value, and the variable type is long. How?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment, long-integer, primitive

This is not new, but I wonder how come java can assign something like, `1L` to `long` datatype.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

where the definition of `long` data type is,

> **long:** The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.
>   It has a minimum value of **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** and a maximum
>   value of **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** (inclusive). Use this data type
>   when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

**From :** [Oracle, Java primitive datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Well, `L` means that you're giving it a long literal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `L` indicates that it is a long. In other words, `1` is an int whereas `1L` is a long. It is specified in the [Java Language Specification #3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int.
>   The suffix L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit 1 (one).

Comment: Huh, I could've sworn there was a specifier for making it a short. I guess I was wrong?

Comment: If by short you mean a "normal" int, then there no specifier (AFAIK).

Comment: By short I meant the data type.

Comment: @DennisMeng I guess I'm tired! No there does not seem to be any specifiers for short.